# Difference between usage of being and having

Tags: word-difference, gerunds

Whenever I read a sentence using having or being, I feel that they are interchangeable. Is it true? For example,

> Do you remember `having` known more than one Amit, Paul, Anu, or John in
>   your life?
>
> Do you remember `being` known more than one Amit, Paul, Anu, or John in
>   your life?

Is there any difference between two sentences? What is the grammar subject for these?

Comment: Short Answer: No. Long Answer: Definitely not interchangeable here. Logging off right now and having a difficult time thinking of an example where they would be interchangeable.

Comment: Being can make a passive construction which is irrelevant to Having

Comment: The second sentence is simply incorrect.  You cannot use *being* in that context, because the statement is "You **have** known more than one Amit, Paul, Anu, or John", not "You **are** known more than one Amit, Paul, Anu, or John."

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is wrong.

I can't quickly think of an example where having and being are interchangeable, but that's not to say there isn't one.